# Discrete Math distinct words

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am asked this:

> "Let m, n, and r be non-negative integers. How many distinct "words"
>   are there consisting of m occurrences of the letter A, n occurrences
>   of the letter B, r occurrences of the letter C, such that no subword
>   of the form CC appears, and no other letters are used?"

This was my method to solve the problem which was incorrect:

> We can find all possible words with length n+m+r where we have n-A's,
>   m-B's, and r-C's :    $$\frac{(n+m+r)!}{n!m!r!}$$
>
> We are asked to find how many distinct words there are such that "no
>   subword of the form CC appears." You can look at this problem in two
>   ways to look at this problem
>     1. We could  use C's and insert letters that would effectively break up adjacent C's
>     2. We could use a string and A's and B's and try to put C's into the string in order to break up the string. Both views will result in the
>   number of subwords with the form CC.
>
> So we know that we are looking for: $\frac{(n+m+r)!}{n!m!r!}$ −number
>   of words with doubles  C′s
>
> So we must now formulate how to find the number of double C forms.
>
> Using the second approach aforementioned we can construct a word with
>   n-A's and m2-B's $n+m\choose m$   ways. In order to appropriately
>   account for overlaps and gaps we can expand on the previous form
>   resulting in : $n+m+1\choose{r}$⇒
>   $\frac{(n+m+1)!}{((r!((n+m+1)−r)!))}$
>
> This effectively  chooses the number of gaps we can insert C into.
>
> So we can calculate the number of words created without the subword CC
>   being repeated by: f(n,m,r)=$\frac{(n+m+r)!}{n!m!r!}$  −
>   $\frac{(n+m+1)!}{((r!((n+m+1)−r)!))}$
>
> So for n=2, m=1, r=2 f(2,1,2)=30 −6⇒24

This was wrong. Can anyone help me with where I went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $\dbinom{m+n}{m}$ words of length $m+n$ that use $m$ A's and $n$ B's.

Any such word determines $m+n+1$ "gaps" (including the $2$ endgaps) into which we can slip a C.

We can choose $r$ of these gaps in $\dbinom{m+n+1}{r}$ ways. The number of words is therefore
$$\binom{m+n}{m}\binom{m+n+1}{r}.$$
(By convention, $\dbinom{a}{b}=0$ if $a\lt b$.)

Comment: Neat, this is even more direct. Small typo: there are $m+n+1$ gaps (it's fine again on the next line anyway).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the typo. Yes, for this problem there is a pleasant direct count.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best possible answer, because it doesn't explain where your solution breaks down, but a different derivation...

Following the same basic principle, you want to know the number of words of the right form that have a CC in them. This has to start somewhere, and there are $n+m+r-1$ places it could start - i.e. the first C in the pair can occur as all but the last letter.

Then you just need to fill up the remaining letters with $n$ As, $m$ Bs and $r-2$ Cs (so we should make some allowances for the cases $r=0$ and $r=1$, when we won't deduct anything at this stage anyway as there are no words with a CC subword).

In the same way you found the total number of words originally, there are:

$$\frac{(n+m+r-2)!}{n!m!(r-2)!}$$

ways of completing the word, having put a CC somewhere. So your answer should be:

$$\frac{(n+m+r)!}{n!m!r!}-\frac{(n+m+r-1)!}{n!m!(r-2)!}$$

(providing $r\geq 2$).

Comment: How can I prove this to further validate the answer. Could I just plug some numbers in like I did in the OP?

Comment: This *is* a proof (assuming I didn't mess up somewhere). It's probably a good idea to try some small examples to check that you (or in this case I) didn't make a mistake.